# How can I combine these two if/else statements for different results?

Tags: php

I currently have these two blocks of php that are pulling results:

```
<?php
    $webtech = article_custom_field('web-tech');
    if ( !empty($webtech) ) :
?>
    <div class="tech-list">
        <div class="tech-title">Technologies:</div>
        <ul class="tech-ul"><?php echo $webtech; ?></ul>
    </div>
<?php
    endif;
?>
```

And

```
<?php
    $url = article_custom_field('site-url');
    elseif ( !empty($url) ) :
?>
    <div class="site-url"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank">Visit</a></div>
<?php
    endif;
?>
```

I want to combine them to output one single block, like:

```
<div class="tech-list">
    <div class="tech-title">Technologies:</div>
    <ul class="tech-ul"><?php echo $webtech; ?></ul>
    <div class="site-url"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank">Visit</a></div>
</div>
```

It needs to meet the following:

If web-tech exists, output it. Don't output site-url if it doesn't exist.

If web-tech exists, output it. If site-url exists, output it.

If site-url exists, output it. Don't output web-tech if it doesn't exist.

The containing div should not be output at all if neither variable does not exist.

Am I missing an obvious way to do it? It seems trivial, but I can't get the if/else/elseif statements to line up.

Comment: Your second condition "...Don't output site-url exists, output it." seems to have a typo, should it read "...If output site-url exists, output it?" or "...If output site-url exists, don't output it?"

Comment: fixed my explanation, above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store your outputs in a variable, like so:

```
<?php
    $output = '';
    $webtech = article_custom_field('web-tech');
    if ( !empty($webtech) ) :
        $output .= '<div class="tech-title">Technologies:</div>'
            . '<ul class="tech-ul">' . $webtech . '</ul>';
    endif;

    $url = article_custom_field('site-url');
    if(!empty($url)) :
        $output .= '<div class="site-url"><a href="' . $url . '" target="_blank">Visit</a></div>';
    endif;

    if($output != ''):
        echo '<div class="tech-list">';
        echo $output;
        echo '</div>';
    endif;
?>
```

This way, only when there is something set in your output variable, will it show anything.

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Yeah, this helps a lot.

Comment: The first <div class="tech-list"> isn't necessary though in the $webtech output

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to check *both* variables before you output the container that they exist in.

```
<?php
    $webtech = article_custom_field('web-tech');
    $url = article_custom_field('site-url');

    if ( !empty($webtech) || !empty($url))
    {
?>
    <div class="tech-list">
<?php
       if ( !empty($webtech) )
       {
?>
        <div class="tech-title">Technologies:</div>
        <ul class="tech-ul"><?php echo $webtech; ?></ul>
<?php
       }

       if ( !empty($url) )
       {
?>
        <div class="site-url"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank">Visit</a></div>
<?php

       }
?>
    </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: This works just as well. It's a matter of preference.

Comment: Indeed. The only functional difference between this answer and the @SanderKoedood answer is that this one preserves the spacing of the HTML formatting. This is useful when you want to look at the final outputted source. However, debugging tools for most modern browsers make the structure of elements clear even without extra whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a or b) then {
  OpenTechTitle;
  if (a) SetAtext;
  if (b) SetBtext;
  CloseTechTitle;
}
```